# Problem with fetching a BLOB column in PHP + MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, blob

Here's the code:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select Data  from sessions');
$stmt->execute();
$x = 234;
$stmt->bind_result($x);
$stmt->fetch();
var_dump($x);
```

This outputs:

> string '' (length=0)

In fact the table contains exactly one row and the blob column contains some valid ASCII character data (a `serialize()`d PHP integer).

Why is this so?

Bump.

Answer (score 0):

MySQLi probably doesn't like putting BLOB data into PHP variables. If you just need to store ASCII data, you should use a column type that's designed to store ASCII.

Comment: The data will include non-ASCII characters as well. As a minimum there will be the NULL character.